# React ref that depends by an element's reference does not get passed to the child components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

The following code creates an object ref that's called **editor**, but as you see it depends by the **contentDiv** element that's a ref to a HTMLElement. After the **editor** object is created it needs to be passed to the TabularRibbon. The problem is that the editor is always null in tabular component. Even if I add a conditional contentDiv?.current, in front of this, it still remains null...

Anyone has any idea?

```
export const Editor = () => {

    let contentDiv = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
    let editor = useRef<Editor>();

    useEffect(() => {
        let options: EditorOptions = { };
        editor.current = new Editor(contentDiv.current, options);
        return () => {
            editor.current.dispose();
        }
    }, [contentDiv?.current])



    return (
        <div >
                <TabularRibbon
                    editor={editor.current}
                />
                <div  ref={contentDiv} />
          ..........
```

Comment: "Mutable values like 'contentDiv.current' aren't valid dependencies because mutating them doesn't re-render the component."

Comment: The useEffect on top of it does the re-rendering, when the contentDiv is updated to a new value.